# postgres creating database using .sql file

Tags: database, bash, postgresql, ubuntu, psql

So I have been trying to create a database using a .sql file. 
The first time we do it, it works perfectly, but it has to work everytime.
If I create a database in postgres myself, the script works perfectly, but if I haven't made the database manually, the script says: psql:*script_name*:40: ERROR: database *dbname* does not exist.

This is the code:

```
 --dit is een psql die eerst de database project dropt, vervolgens
--maakt hij opnieuw de database project aan.
--De de tabellen die hierbij worden gemaakt zijn:
--Pathway_C1, Eiwit_C1, Gen_C1, Gen_Go_C1, Go_termen_c1 en Gen_kegg_C1

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.5.14
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.14

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;


--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

DROP DATABASE project;

CREATE DATABASE project; 

\c project

CREATE TABLE Pathway_C1 (
    Kegg_co CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Kegg_co)
);

CREATE TABLE Go_termen_C1 (
    Go_nummer CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Go_functie VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Go_nummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Gen_C1 (
    Gen_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Gen_naam VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Gen_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Eiwit_C1 (
    Eiwit_ID CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    Gen_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Eiwit_naam VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    Eiwit_Lengte INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Eiwit_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Gen_ID) REFERENCES Gen_C1(Gen_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Gen_Kegg_C1 (
    Gen_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Kegg_co CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Gen_ID, Kegg_co),
    FOREIGN KEY (Kegg_co) REFERENCES Pathway_C1(Kegg_co),
    FOREIGN KEY (Gen_ID) REFERENCES Gen_C1(Gen_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Gen_Go_C1 (
    Gen_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Go_nummer CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Gen_ID, Go_nummer),
    FOREIGN KEY (Gen_ID) REFERENCES Gen_C1(Gen_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Go_nummer) REFERENCES Go_termen_C1(Go_nummer)
);



GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO username; 

--
-- Name: SCHEMA public; Type: ACL; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;



--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--enter code here
```

Please don't pay attention to the comments we put in the script, they are not really important.

Answer (score 0):

For this example I'll assume that the user is postgres.

1. login as user **postgres**

   `sudo -i -u postgres`
2. export your database as .sql or .psql

   `pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 db_name > db_name.sql`
3. The file is located in **/var/lib/postgresql/**
4. Move the file to your project directory e.g

   `mv db_name.sql ../../../home/projects/web/My_App/backend/`
5. Logout user postgres and continue as the **system user**
6. create **setup.sql** file to write commands that will be executed on the database to create the table and grant privileges

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE db_name;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_name TO postgres;
   ```
7. create a bash script to automate the process. the file can be named **setup.sh** and placed in the root directory of your project

   ```
   sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 < /home/projects/web/My_App/backend/setup.sql"

   sudo -U postgres bash -c "psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d db_name < /home/projects/web/My_App/backend/db_name.sql"
   ```
8. Run the bash script

   `bash setup.sh`

Please remember to change db_name, and file paths to fit the names you have in your file system.

Answer (score -2):

You could add a line at the top of your script:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

The [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) on `CREATE DATABASE`.

Also, it looks like your script was created with `pg_dump`.  `pg_dump` has lots of options and flags you can pass to it.  One of those flags is `--create`.

From the [PostgreSQL Documentation on the pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) `--create` flag:

> Begin the output with a command to create the database itself and
>   reconnect to the created database. (With a script of this form, it
>   doesn't matter which database in the destination installation you
>   connect to before running the script.) If --clean is also specified,
>   the script drops and recreates the target database before reconnecting
>   to it.